# Calling C wrapper functions from within others

Tags: c++, c, wrapper

I am unable to run the code below. How do I get a C++ function with a C wrapper able to call another function with the same properties?

It is returning the error:

Error:
`library.cpp:11:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ifelseFn'
    ifelseFn();
    ^`

Code:

```
#include "library.h"
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void loopFn() {
    int sum = 0;
    std::cout << "Adding loop function call...\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    std::cout << "Sum of value for for loop is: " << sum << std::endl;

    ifelseFn();
}

extern "C" void whileFn() {
    int sum = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    std::cout << "Adding while function call...\n";
    while (i < 5) {
        sum += i;
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << "Sum of value for while loop is: " << sum << std::endl;
}

extern "C" void ifelseFn() {
    std::cout << "Adding ifelse function call...\n";
    if (0) {
        std::cout << "If portion!\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Else portion!\n";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    loopFn();

    return 0;
}
```

**Problem was solved by adding this header file.**

library.h

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

extern "C" void loopFn();
extern "C" void whileFn();
extern "C" void ifelseFn();

#endif
```

Comment: You need to #include the header file that declares ifelseFn. It hasn't been seen at the point you try to use it.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with wrapper functions or `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifelseFn` is defined after it's used.

You should either move its definition before it's used or add a declaration before its first usage, e.g. :

```
extern "C" void ifelseFn();
```

At the beginning of the file or in an header file you include.

Comment: That worked! I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm able to.